# Pulling values from inner curly brackets

Tags: apex, deserialize, key, get

I am trying to pull the values from a JSON response and have managed to get most of the values except the one I need which is nested in an inner set of curly brackets

```
public class web_ser {

@future(callout=true)
public static void web_services_rest(String order_JSON){

    String payload_JSON =  order_JSON;
    String endpoint = 'https://some_website.com';

    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    Http http = new Http();

    request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setBody(payload_JSON);

    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

    System.debug(response.toString());
    System.debug('STATUS: ' + response.getStatus());
    System.debug('STATUS_CODE: ' + response.getStatusCode());

    String responseJSON = response.getBody();
    System.debug('responseJSON: ' + responseJSON);

    Map<String, Object> deserialized_JSON_response = 
        (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseJSON);

    Object message = deserialized_response.get('message');
    System.debug('message: ' + message);
}}
```

The output from message looks something like this:

```
responseJSON: {"status": "100", "code": "success", "message": "{order_number:00001979,id_number:I-00000982-10}"}
```

The information I'm trying to pull, **id_number**, is in the message portion of the deserialized JSON packet:

```
"message": "{order_number:00001979,id_number:I-00000982-10}"
```

I am able to to put message into a variable but have been unable to extract the value for the key **id_number**. What am I missing to be able to access **id_number**?

Comment: Probably worth a look at the example here in [JSON.deserializeUntyped()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) and specifically look at how they retrieve the `dimensions` attribute data - which is similar to what you are requesting above.

Comment: @MarkPond I tried following that example but all my system debugs start to fail. 'Map<String, Object> essage = (Map<String, Object>) deserialized_response.get('message');
        System.debug('message: ' + message);'
 My system debug does not print at all and any system debug after, seem's like, is dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the interior value(s) of `message` is not JSON:

```
"message": "{order_number:00001979,id_number:I-00000982-10}"
```

you'll need to use string class methods as in:

```
String IdNumber = messageVbl.substringBetween('id_number:','}');
```

Comment: I get the following error 'Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void substringBetween(String, String) from the type Map<String,Object>'

Comment: All sorts of ways to get that value out... you could use a regex match or string slicing using index of etc. But with the example above you need to first get the message value out of the untyped parsed JSON map into a string... that is what messageVbl clearly is.

Comment: @Richard, I'm assuming you have already extracted the `message` property into some string variable; if it is still in a map, you'll need to fetch from the map

Comment: @PhilW and cropedy Thank you guys! I got it working properly

Comment: I didn't even notice that the content wasn't a JSON object! @Richard if you've got the ability to get it changed, I would ask the developer of the remote endpoint to send you back proper JSON if they can do so. (Future developers will thank you)